# Unattended phpmyadmin install end up throwing errors

Tags: phpmyadmin, unattended-upgrades

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin preseeding the information via the debconf-set-selection command on my Ubuntu 12.04LTS

That's the bit I'm using

```
echo phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true | debconf-set-selections
echo phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password pwd | debconf-set-selections
echo phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password pwd| debconf-set-selections
echo phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password pwd| debconf-set-selections
echo phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2 | debconf-set-selections
echo phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/upgrade-backup boolean true | debconf-set-selections
```

But I always end up getting the following error message

```
error: Cannot find a question for phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install
error: Cannot find a question for phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm
error: Cannot find a question for phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass
error: Cannot find a question for phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass
error: Cannot find a question for phpmyadmin/upgrade-backup
```

if I attempt to run the command using sudo from the shell I get the following message

```
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
```

However, I was once able to get this installed. So what could be the cause?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to a debconf bug:
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=487300

Your debconf database could have got corrupted.

Running `/usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl` can fix it.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Awesome. This command worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Running: `sudo /usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl` can fix it.

Remember to install mysql server, because you need a connection to the socket. Unattended is also:

```
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root" | sudo debconf-set-selections

apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server -y
```

With high privileges, the final installation would be:

```
echo 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password root' | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password root' | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password root' | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2' | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin -y
```

With that everything works very well.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, add more `sudos` ... this is what worked for my unattended MySQL install:

```
sudo echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password ${DB_PASSWORD_ROOT}" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

As with the OP, my scripts previously ran fine as root without any `sudo` prefixes at all. So I'm not sure why in certain cases or environments this matters:

https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/ss-install-mysql.txt

By the way, thanks to those who shared this snippet:

`sudo /usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl` ... intriguing if nothing else!